# Why Rails 4.2 app create log files with root permissions when deploy it on Ubuntu server using Ansible during running rake db:migrate task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, file-permissions, rake-task

Scope of problem

- Rails `4.2.11`
- Ansible `2.1.1.0`
- Ubuntu `14`
- Ubuntu user: `deploy`

I have Rails app which I deploy to Ubuntu server by Ansible script.

I have problem of understanding why Rails app create log files with root permissions when Ansible script execute rake tasks.

[image]

In my example it's running `rake db:migrate` but also same behaviour with `rake assets:precompile`

You can see by photo below that application is deployed via user 'deploy' but after run of rake task it create 2 log files with root permission. After restart of web server it crash with permission denied error, so I need manually change ownership to `deploy:deploy`

[image]

Structure of Rails logger is also looks suspicious. You can check `@dev=IO:<STDERR>` value. I've checked in another project and there I can see something like `@dev=#<File:/var/www/.../log/production.log>`

[image]

I tried to explore source code of `ror4` but so far no luck to understand from there what is happening. Only idea is could be that Rails raise exception when create log file and `STDERR` become output

Please help if you have similar problem or can point out where I can look to.

Answer (score 0):

The rake script runs as root User.

To answer the question you must add the complete ansible script or the bundle script if you manually add a "sudo" commands or something unusual.

There are different possible positions to define the user in ansible.

Read the become section of the ansible documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Or give a try with

```
- name: Run db:migrate
  shell: ... rake cmd ...
  become: yes
  become_user: deploy
  become_method: su
```

Change the become_method to your needs e.g become_flags: '-s /bin/sh' or sudo